# How to use await in a forEach loop in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of users and I want to check how many of them are joined to my telegram channel and my checking method is an async method and I can use the method like this:

```
check(user)
    .then((res) => {
    if(res) {
       // user is joined 
      }
    else {
       // user is not joined
    }
})
```

But I don't know how to use this method for an array of users.

I have tested this code :

```
members = 0;
users.forEach((user) => {
            check(user)
                .then((result) => {
                    if(result) {
                          members++;
                      }
                });
        })
```

But this code is definitely wrong because I don't know when should I send the result to my admin (the person who want to check how many users are joined). I put the sending method after the `forEach` but It shows a very low number(near 0).

I searched and I found a keyword `await` and I tried it in an async method:

```
async function checkMembership() {
    let data;
    await check(user)
        .then((res) => {
            data = res
        });
    console.log(data);
}
```

and It works well but when I use the `await` in forEach loop like this:

```
users.forEach((user) => {
            await check(user)
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                });
        })
```

I got the following error:
`SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`.
How should I handle this magical forEach loop?

UPDATE-1:
I have tested this code too but I got the previous error:

```
async function checkMembership() {

    User.find({}, (err, res) => {
        for(let user of res) {
            await check(user)
                .then((ress) => {
                console.log(ress)
                })
        }
        console.log('for is finished');
  });
}
```

UPDATE-2:

This code didn't work too:

```
Promise.all(users.map(check))
            .then((Res) => {
                console.log(Res);
            })
```

and I got the following error:

`TypeError: #<Promise> is not a function`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For using `await` keyword you need to define the function with `async` keyword,
e.g.

```
users.forEach(async (user) => {
  await check(user)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  })
```

However this code is most likely not the thing you want as it is going to fire async calls without waiting for them to finish ([Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop))

To make it properly you can use `Promise.all`, e.g.

```
Promise.all(users.map(check)).then((results) => {
  //results is array of all promise results, in your case it should be
  // smth like [res, false|null|undefined, res, ...]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library which has a built-in forEach, then process the result in the callback. Great tutorial [here](http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice)

Edit - Here is the example form Sebastian Eilund:

```
async.forEach(users, function(user, callback) {
  //do stuff
  callback();
}, function (err) {
  //finished doing stuff for all users
});
```